# Pass Property to User Defined Function

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to read up on feeding arguments to a function in VBA (just started looking at VBA), and cannot find any examples that help me understand the specific scenario I want.

I have a function:

```
Public Function myFunction()
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart1", "Chart2", "Chart3""))
    .Visible = Not .Visible
  End With
End Function
```

Which I then call like this:

```
Sub myMacro()
  trigger = myFunction()
End Sub
```

What I want to do instead of having ".visible" and "Not .visible" properties passed to my function from my Sub. For example if I have multiple functions:

```
Public Function myFunction1(visibility)
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart1", "Chart2", "Chart3""))
    .Visible = visibility
  End With
End Function

Public Function myFunction2(visibility)
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart4", "Chart5", "Chart6""))
    .Visible = visibility
  End With
End Function

Sub myMacro1()
  Dim showit
  showit = .Visible
  Dim hideit
  hideit = Not .Visible

 showCharts = myFunction1(showit)
 HideCharts = myFunction2(hideit)
End Sub

Sub myMacro2()
  Dim showit
  showit = .Visible
  Dim hideit
  hideit = Not .Visible

 showCharts = myFunction1(hideit)
 HideCharts = myFunction2(showit)
End Sub
```

How do I achieve this? If I wrap "showit" and "hideit" values in quotation marks, it will be passed with the quotation marks. If I do like above and don't have quotation marks, it does not pass it at all

**Update:** I made it work with the "As Variant" declaration and the information about using True and False suggested by @Viktor. Solution posted below.

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem. I hope this solution is flexible enough to use.
In myMacro you can put the names of the charts following by their required visibility (true or false).
The function SetVisibility try to set the visibility. If it fails, returns false, that can be used for displaying a message.

```
Sub myMacro()
    If Not SetVisibility("Chart1", False) Then MsgBox "Setting visibility failed"
    If Not SetVisibility("Chart2", False) Then MsgBox "Setting visibility failed"
    If Not SetVisibility("Chart3", False) Then MsgBox "Setting visibility failed"
    If Not SetVisibility("Chart4", False) Then MsgBox "Setting visibility failed"
End Sub

Function SetVisibility(psShapeName As String, pbVisibility As Boolean) As Boolean
    SetVisibility = True
    On Error GoTo errHandler
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(psShapeName).Visible = pbVisibility
    Exit Function
errHandler:
    SetVisibility = False
End Function
```

Comment: Not really sure I get it. Where do I define which shapes should be updated? For example Chart1, Chart2 and Chart3 belong together, just as Chart4, Chart5 and Chart6 belong together.

Comment: I found a way. See posted answer. Feel free to suggest a way to make the readability and stability or whatever better if you see a reason and motivation for it. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I made it work with the "As Variant" declaration and the information about using True and False suggested by @Viktor

```
Public Function myFunction1(visibility As Variant)
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart1", "Chart2", "Chart3"))
    .Visible = visibility
  End With
End Function

Public Function myFunction2(visibility As Variant)
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart4", "Chart5", "Chart6"))
    .Visible = visibility
  End With
End Function

Sub myMacro1()
  Dim showit
  showit = True
  Dim hideit
  hideit = False

  showCharts = myFunction1(showit)
  hideCharts = myFunction2(hideit)
End Sub

Sub myMacro2()
  Dim showit
  showit = True
  Dim hideit
  hideit = False

  showCharts = myFunction2(showit)
  hideCharts = myFunction1(hideit)
End Sub
```

Not sure this is the best way of doing it, but it works fine!

As I will have even more sets of charts I want to show/hide, I can just create a function for the different sets, and add a "hide" for all of the ones that are not the ones that should be shows (so each sub will call one "show" function, and pass "hide" to all the rest). Simple enough for readability.

Comment: For clarity yoy could use `Boolean` instead of `Variant`: `myFunction2(visibility As Boolean)`.

Comment: And also you don't need `With...End With` construction.

Comment: @freeflow damn, that would have been nice (Rubberduck VBA) - I was actually thinking about how this feature was missing from the editor, as I've used it in Visual Studio Code and also in PHPStorm before for other languages. Unfortunately it's a company PC and the org. is too big to hoping for an access to/permission for third party addins. For Option Explicit, this is just to tell me if I fail to declare variables with "Dim" for example?

Comment: @JohnyL Tried changing to Boolean instead, then I got an error on "showit" in `showCharts = myFunction1(showit)` When I removed `With` and `End with` it threw an error on `.Visible =`.

Comment: It should be jus `ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart4", "Chart5", "Chart6")).Visible = visibility`.

Comment: *Tried changing to Boolean instead, then I got an error on "showit"* Then you're passing not Boolean.

Comment: @JohnyL Got it working. I had `Dim showit` instead of `Dim showit As Boolean` for example, and also for the `With` and `End With` it didn't work because I had `.Visible =` on a separate line. Thanks!

Comment: The .visible property of a ShapeRange object is a Long  which holds a value from the MsoTristate Enum,.   Hence declaring variables which need to be MsoTristate as boolean won't work. Hence visibility should be declared as Type MsoTriState and you should use msoTrue (-1) instead of true and msoFalse (0).  These latter values will show up in the intellisense if you declare visibility as MsoTriState.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type